# How to listen to validate method in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to implement my own custom date picker component using vuetify .

Here is my code for component

```
    <template>
    <v-layout wrap class="px-0 mx-0" style="position: relative">
        <span class="date-label">{{label}}</span>
        <v-layout class="px-1" row style="border-style: solid;border-width: thin;border-radius: 5px;"
                  wrap>
            <v-flex xs4 class="pa-1">
                <v-autocomplete
                    :items="days_array"
                    class="custom"
                    flat
                    solo
                    hide-details
                    error-messages="This field is required"
                    label="Day *"
                    style="padding: 0;"
                    v-model="dob.day"
                />
            </v-flex>

            <v-flex style="padding-right: 8px;" xs4 class="pa-1">
                <v-autocomplete
                    :items="months"
                    class="custom"
                    flat
                    solo
                    hide-details
                    item-text="value"
                    item-value="number"
                    label="Month *"
                    style="padding: 0;"
                    v-model="dob.month"
                />
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex style="padding-right: 8px;" xs4 class="pa-1">
                <v-autocomplete
                    :items="years"
                    class="custom"
                    flat
                    solo
                    hide-details
                    label="Year *"
                    style="padding: 0;"
                    type="text"
                    v-model="dob.year"
                />
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
    import {validationMixin} from "../mixins/validationMixin";
    //
    export default {
        name: "NewDatePicker",
        props: ['label', 'value', 'maxYear', 'minYear', 'watchValue'],
        data() {
            return {
                dob: {
                    year: null,
                    month: null,
                    day: null
                },
                years: [],
                days_array: [],
                months: [
                    {
                        number: '01',
                        value: 'JAN'
                    },
                    {
                        number: '02',
                        value: 'FEB'
                    },
                    {
                        number: '03',
                        value: 'MAR'
                    },
                    {
                        number: '04',
                        value: 'APR'
                    },
                    {
                        number: '05',
                        value: 'MAY'
                    },
                    {
                        number: '06',
                        value: 'JUN'
                    },
                    {
                        number: '07',
                        value: 'JUL'
                    },
                    {
                        number: '08',
                        value: 'AUG'
                    },
                    {
                        number: '09',
                        value: 'SEP'
                    },
                    {
                        number: '10',
                        value: 'OCT'
                    },
                    {
                        number: '11',
                        value: 'NOV'
                    },
                    {
                        number: '12',
                        value: 'DEC'
                    }

                ]
            }
        },
        mixins: [validationMixin],
        computed: {
            year_value() {
                return this.dob.year + '-' + this.dob.month + '-' + this.dob.day;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            handleError() {
               console.log(123);
            }
        },
        watch: {
            year_value() {
                this.$emit('input', this.year_value)
            },
            value() {
                if (this.value && this.watchValue) {
                    this.dob.year = parseInt(this.value.substr(0, 4));
                    this.dob.month = this.value.substr(5, 2);
                    this.dob.day = this.value.substr(8, 2);
                }
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            let currentYear = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 4);
            currentYear = parseInt(currentYear);
            let years_array = [];
            let maximumYear = currentYear + 12;
            let minimumYear = 2015;
            if (this.maxYear) {
                maximumYear = this.maxYear;
            }
            if (this.minYear) {
                minimumYear = this.minYear;
            }


            for (let i = minimumYear; i <= maximumYear; i++) {
                years_array.push(i);
            }
            years_array = years_array.reverse();
            this.years = years_array;
            const days_array = [];

            for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
                let value = i < 10 ? ('0' + i) : i.toString();
                days_array.push(value)
            }
            this.days_array = days_array;
            if (this.value) {
                this.dob.year = parseInt(this.value.substr(0, 4));
                this.dob.month = this.value.substr(5, 2);
                this.dob.day = this.value.substr(8, 2);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .custom.v-text-field > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot:before {
        border-style: none;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: -40px;
    }

    .custom.v-text-field > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot:after {
        border-style: none;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: -40px;
    }

    .date-label {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 4;
        margin-top: -10px;
        background: white;
        padding-left: 3px;
        padding-right: 3px;

    }
</style>
```

However the problem is I want to write custom required validation for this component .On other parts of the form I do

```
this.$refs.formRef.validate();
```

Is there a way to listen to validate method call in the mounted method of component ?

Comment: What do you mean by custom required validation?

Comment: I want to combine validation message using three fields

Comment: Can you create a codepen to reproduce this issue, that would really help to solve your issue faster